# How long Ethereum hash length? (block, transaction, address)

Tags: hash, ethereum, string-length

I checked hash length from node data, like below(include '0x').

- block hash: 66
- transaction hash: 66
- receipt root: 66
- address: 40

Is it always a fixed length?
Or is it variable length?

Comment: Have a search on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/, probably better asked there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's always fixed length.

- Block hash is calculated using the [keccak256](https://ethereum.org/en/glossary/#keccak-256) algorithm that always results in 32 bytes (64 hex characters prepended by `0x`) no matter the input length.
- Same goes for transaction hash and receipt root hash.
- An address is always the [last 20 bytes](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/accounts/#account-creation) (40 hex charaters prepended by `0x`) of the public key hash.